# libgdx 0.98 how to check touch event while actor is rotate?

Tags: rotation, libgdx

I am writing a game.i want the user touch a rotate actor.

I am tried  setBounds method to handle touchevent,but it too complicate when the actor is rotating.

Is there any simple way ? thank you.

Comment: Usually you don't need to do anything. At least nowadays. You would do everything in your standard non-rotated local coordinates and when you use rotation on the actor itself, the Stage should automatically handle all this. To enable rotation on actors, you might have to use `actor.setTransform(true)`.

Comment: I don't quite understand.Can u explain it more clearly.thank u!

Answer (score 0):

Call it on `touchDown` or `touchUp` method in class implements `InputProcessor`. (x,y - are click point coordinates)

```
Vector2 coordinates; - coordinates of your object
float width, height; - size of your object.

public boolean isTouched(float x, float y) {
    if (x < coordinates.x
            || x > coordinates.x + width)
        return false;
    if (y < coordinates.y - heightImprover
            || y > coordinates.y + height)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I tried this way.It can get touch event when the actor move on the straight.I want get touch event while  rotating an actor.